# recoding variable returns "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r

I have spent a couple hours trying to figure this out:
I need to reverse-code a variable. I have 3 identical variables at 3 differnet timepoints. The first 2 are easily recoded, but the third returns "undefined columns selected", even though I copy-paste the code. I also tried different versions of the same code, and have the same problem. 
When I do print(dat$cuppass) it returns printed values, with 1 NA. I had similarly 1 or 2 NAs with the previous 2 timepoints, and have not had a problems when applying complete.cases.
Could anyone figure out how to recode 3d variable?

Thank you!!

## these work:

```
dat$cdppassr <- 5-dat$cdppass[complete.cases(dat[dat$cdppass])]
print(dat$cdppassr)
dat$pdppassr <- 5-dat$pdppass[complete.cases(dat[dat$pdppass])]
print(dat$pdppassr)
```

## Neither this,

```
dat$cuppassr <- 5-dat$cuppass[na.omit(dat[dat$cuppass])]
```

## nor this works:

```
dat$cuppassr <- recode[na.omit(dat$cuppass,'0=5; 1=4; 2=3; 3=2; 4=1; 5=0')]

> print(cuppass)<br/>
  [1]  5  5  5  5  4  3  4  3  3  3  5  4  5  3  5  5  3  3  5  3  3  3  3  4  3  3  4  2<br/>
 [29]  3  3  5  2  3  2  5  3  3  4  5  3  4  5  3  5  4  5  5  4  3  5  3  5  3  4  3  5<br/>
 [57]  4  5  4  4  4  3  3  5  4  4  5  5  3  4  4  4  3  3  3  5  5  5  3  5  3  4  3  3<br/>
 [85]  2  4  3  3  4  5  2  5  5  3  4  4  3  5  5  5  3  5  5  5  3  5  5  3  5  3  5  5<br/>
[113]  4  5  5  3  3  5  3  2  5  5  5  5  4  5  3  5  4  5  5  5  5  4  5  5  3  5  5  5<br/>
[141]  3  5  5  5  3  3  2  5  4  2  3  5  4  5  5  3  3  5  5  5  3  3  5  5  5 NA  3  3<br/>
[169]  5  5  5  5  5  3  5  5  3  5  5  4  5  4  3  5  4  3  2  5  3  3  4  3  5  2  4  5<br/>
[197]  5  3  5  4  4  4  4  2  5  5  4  5  3  2  4  5  4  5  5  5  3  3  5  5  5  3  3  5<br/>
[225]  5  4  2  5  5  3  5  5  3  3  5  4  5  5  0  3  3  5  3  3  4  3  3  1  5  5  5  5<br/>
[253]  5  3  4  5  4  5  5  5  3  5  5  2  5  5  2  3  5  4  5  5  5  3  4  3  3  5  3  3<br/>
[281]  3  3  5  5  3  3  2  5  4  5  3  4  3  4  3  5  4  3  5  5  3  5  5  3  5  5  5  5<br/>
[309]  5  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  4  5  5  3  4  4  5  5  5  5  3  5  3  5  3  5  5  5  5  2<br/>
[337]  3  0  3  3  5  3  3  5  3  4  4  5  5  5  5  3  5  5  3  4  3  5  4  5  4  5  3  2<br/>
[365]  3  3  5  3  5  5  3  4  4  5  5  5  4  5  3  5  3  3  5  3  5  3  5  3  3  5  5  2<br/>
[393]  3  3  5  5  4  3  5  4  3  3  4  3<br/>
```

Comment: `na.omit` is different than `complete.cases`. Not exactly a copy paste. Try to use `complete.cases` again.

Comment: `recode` needs parenthesis not brakets

Comment: I see, my second code is wrong. But what about the first one, with complete.cases? That's the one I copy-pasted, and it won't work...

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: sure, I'm not home right now but I'll attach it tonight. Thank you!